# Case Sensitivity of MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, linux, database, ubuntu

I am developing a JSP, Servlet (pure jsp and servlet) application with hibernate.

I know that in "most" linux systems, the MySQL table names and database names are case sensitive, while in windows and Apple it is the other way around. I just learnt this in the hard way, ended up replacing table names in database and my java code.

However I can only test in Ubuntu. I do have "column" names with mixed cases. For an example, some columns of the table "employee" are `idEmployee`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `HomeAddress`, `PhoneNumber`etc.

I know ubuntu is not making trouble with the case sensitivity of table "column" names, but what about other linux systems? Is there any linux/unix OS where it is case sensitive for the "column names" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have to worry.  The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) is clear that column aliases are not case sensitive:

> Column, index, stored routine, and event names are not case sensitive
>   on any platform, nor are column aliases.
>
> . . .
>
> By default, table aliases are case sensitive on Unix, but not so on
>   Windows or OS X.

If I had to speculate why the case sensitivity follows the default case sensitivity of the underlying operating system, I would guess that under some circumstances (particularly long ago when MySQL was being developed), tables are stored in files under their own names.  Now it is controlled by the `lower_case_table_names` system variable, which simply has different defaults on different operating systems.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So to make a long explanation short, I don't have to worry about this because table "column" names are not case sensitive in any platform. Isn't it?

Comment: @JustCause . . . You don't have to worry about the case sensitivity of column names.